# AVCaptureSession OnFrame Event?

Tags: xamarin.ios, avcapturesession

I am trying to make an application that will "trigger" when a certain image is shown on screen. I have the app streaming the camera to the screen inside the app using AVCaptureSession. Now i was wondering how to make some sort of EventHandler for each frame of the video, in which i will check to see if the image contains one of my triggers. Does anyone know the best way to handle this? I could not find any resources on an OnFrame EventHandler for AVCaptureSession.

This is the tutorial i followed for showing the camera on screen
https://github.com/messier16/FullCameraPage/blob/master/FullCameraApp.iOS/CameraPageRenderer.cs

Any advice is awesome. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing a while loop inside of overriden ViewWillAppear() to grab the frame consistently